# Cakephp - Application do function

Tags: php, mysql, function, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have a question. Is there a possibility in Cakephp but also in PHP in general, to write a function that will do something by itself without user interaction?
I mean, for example, to change the status of a record based on the date.
If now () is bigger than "start_date", then the function, change status to "completed". Until now, the user always had to change the status in edit view.

My Lesson table has these field:

```
ID, Title, Start_date, Add_user, description, status
```

I am using Cakephp 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Command (Shell for CakePHP v3.5 and less) in your CakePHP application to check each row in your database to see if the date has passed your timer and run a cron job to run that Command every X time.

[Console Tools, Shells & Tasks](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html) - For examples of Commands

In your Command you will have a function which gets your row from the database, checks to see if `now() > start_date` and if true then set the status to expired or true or whatever.

Then run the Command every minute or hour via a cron job - [Cron Job Tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800)

Comment: Surely instead of looking at all rows, you'd build a query that selects only rows where the status has not been updated and the date condition is true. Or even just executes an `update` query instead of `select`, `foreach` and `save`.

Comment: Yeah of course you would only select rows which haven't been given a status or are in a current state of needing to be checked, although the question is vague at best and if no effort is put into asking for help then a detailed response isn't going to be given.